# Android app update issue in Google play while uploading the app-bundle

Tags: android, apk, bundle, android-app-bundle, app-update

I use to upload APK's to google play regularly, but this time i have uploaded the App bundle, post update few users are getting the update and few users are not getting any update option, i have done the Rollout for 100%. also i have tried the following

1.uninstall the app and installed the new one (worked)
2.clear the cache of google play and visited (worked)

But my problem is all users can't follow any of the mentioned points, and my question is why it's behaving like this.

Comment: How long did they wait?

Comment: @Pierre they waited for more than a day